# Save jaw only as image with dlib facial landmark detection and the rest to be transparent

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, dlib

I already have a facial landmark detector and can already save the image using opencv and dlib with the code below:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2


# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True, help="Path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="Path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create the facial landmark predictor
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])

# load the input image, resize it, and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# detect faces in the grayscale image
rects = detector(gray, 1)

for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
    # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
    # convert the landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

    # loop over the face parts individually
    print(face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS.items())
    for (name, (i, j)) in face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS.items():
        print(" i = ", i, " j = ", j)
        # clone the original image so we can draw on it, then 
        # display the name of the face part of the image
        clone = image.copy()
        cv2.putText(clone, name, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # loop over the subset of facial landmarks, drawing the 
        # specific face part using a red dots
        for (x, y) in shape[i:j]:
            cv2.circle(clone, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        # extract the ROI of the face region as a separate image
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(np.array([shape[i:j]]))
        roi = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi = imutils.resize(roi, width=250, inter=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        # show the particular face part
        cv2.imshow("ROI", roi)
        cv2.imwrite(name + '.jpg', roi)
        cv2.imshow("Image", clone)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    # visualize all facial landmarks with a transparent overly
    output = face_utils.visualize_facial_landmarks(image, shape)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have Arnold's face and I save part of his face using `opencv imwrite`.

[image: Arnold]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the image of the jaw only and I don't want to save the neck part. See the image below:

[image: Arnold_2]

Does anyone has an idea on how I can remove the other parts, except the jaw detected by `dlib`.

Something like this is the expected output:
[image: Arnold_3]

Comment: can you explain *get the jaw image only*, with some illustrated examples ?

Comment: @ZdaR i have updated my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Original image] + [image: The generated mask] = [image: Transparent version]

It's not very clear how much of the original image you are trying to mask off. Assuming you are using `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`, DLib's landmarks 0 to 16 define the jawline, so you could make a mask that extends these to cover the bottom half of the frame.

Pardon my crude python skillset but that code will mask off below the jawline and also cut the image to the region of interest to match the expected output in your question.

[image: Cropped masked image]

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2
import os

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')

# load image
img = cv2.imread('thegovernator.png')
h, w, ch = img.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# add an alpha channel to image
b,g,r = cv2.split(img);
a = np.ones((h,w,1), np.uint8) * 255
img = cv2.merge((b, g, r, a))
# detect face
rects = detector(gray,1)
roi = rects[0] # region of interest
shape = predictor(gray, roi)
shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
# extract jawline
jawline = shape[0:17]
top = min(jawline[:,1])
bottom = max(jawline[:,1])
# extend contour for masking
jawline = np.append(jawline, [ w-1, jawline[-1][1] ]).reshape(-1, 2)
jawline = np.append(jawline, [ w-1, h-1 ]).reshape(-1, 2)
jawline = np.append(jawline, [ 0, h-1 ]).reshape(-1, 2)
jawline = np.append(jawline, [ 0, jawline[0][1] ]).reshape(-1, 2)
contours = [ jawline ]
# generate mask
mask = np.ones((h,w,1), np.uint8) * 255 # times 255 to make mask 'showable'
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, 0, -1) # remove below jawline
# apply to image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
result = result[top:bottom, roi.left():roi.left()+roi.width()] # crop ROI
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result); 
cv2.imshow('masked image', result)
```

Comment: How does this not answer your question? What is wrong or missing? Just curious.

Comment: Im still trying out to work and use this on different images. I still could not use this on other images.

Comment: Just tried it on a couple random faces from a google search ... had to fix the calculation of max Y for ROI cutting. Try it again. It works for me.

Comment: i've fixed it with bottom = max(jawline[:, 1]) is there a way to remove the eye and upper part of the image?

Comment: Modify the ROI used to trimmed the final image ... I've just done it. I'm done with this question as it feels like I'm doing your homework now. Feel free to accept it.